# Script for finding "Like" PCs in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Im trying to write a script for prompting a User to get info on computers based in AD. It works without the Filter being applied. But when adding the filter the code breaks. Is the syntax wrong for the filter? Im sure its an easy fix but i am stummped. Yes this is being ran as administrator.

```
$computerName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the computer Name you are looking for.' 
Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like $computerName" -Properties IPv4Address | FT Name,DNSHostName,IPv4Address -A
Write-Host "You input Computer $computerName"
```

Comment: You would only need `-Filter "*$computerName*"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for your filter should be, if using `-Filter`:

```bash
Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '*$computerName*'"
```

And if using `-LDAPFilter`:

```bash
Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(cn=*$computerName*)"
```

See [**about_ActiveDirectory_Filter**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)) for details.